For a Markov process, does a larger spectral gap imply faster convergence to the invariant distribution?
Say I have two time-homogeneous Markov processes $(X_t)_{t\ge0}$ and $(Y_t)_{t\ge0}$ which both admit $\pi$ as their unique invariant measure. Let $A$ and $B$ denote their generators on $L^2(\pi)$ and define their Dirichlet forms by $$\mathcal E(f,g):=-\langle f,Ag\rangle_{L^2(\pi)}$$ and $$\mathcal F(f,g):=-\langle f,Bg\rangle_{L^2(\pi)}$$ for $f,g\in L^2(\pi)$. Say I was able to show that $$\mathcal E(f,f)=\mathcal F(f,f)+c\operatorname{Var}_\mu[f]\;\;\;\text{for all }f\in L^2(\pi)\tag1$$ for some $c>0$ and a probability measure $\mu$.
Question: Can I immediately infer that

$(X_t)_{t\ge0}$ has a larger spectral gap than $(Y_t)_{t\ge0}$?
The law of $X_t$ will converge "faster" to $\pi$ than the law of $Y_t$ as $t\to\infty$? (with respect to which metric?)

I think (1.) should immediately follow from $(1)$. And (1.) should directly imply (2.), but I'm not sure about the metric.
